# InterSystems Cache SQL. Check if table exists

Tags: intersystems-cache

What SQL query can I use to check if a table exists.

I need to support different versions of schema, and some deployments can miss certain tables

Comment: Are the tables in cache Or externally connected via jdbc/odbc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are Cache tables, you may use the `%Dictionary.CompiledClass` system table.

```
select id from %Dictionary.CompiledClass where SqlSchemaName='%BI' and SqlTableName='Alerts'
```

Or, if you know Cache class name of your table,

```
select id from %Dictionary.CompiledClass where ID='%BI.Alerts'
```

These queries will return 1 row if table %BI.Alerts exists.